# How to stop logged in user from accessing Admin rights by changing URL in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am trying to learn PHP and I have created two types of users in my web app - 1. Alumni and 2. Admin. While I m logged in as Alumni and change my URL to ../admin , I m getting access to all admin functions which I should not. I can't seem to understand how to handle this. What I want is when I am logged in as Alumni and change my URL I want to be redirected to login.php of Admin . Below is my code :
index.php (admin)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    
<?php session_start(); ?>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">

  <title><?php echo isset($_SESSION['system']['name']) ? $_SESSION['system']['name'] : '' ?></title>
    

<?php
  if(!isset($_SESSION['login_id']))
    header('location:login.php');
 include('./header.php'); 
 // include('./auth.php'); 
 ?>

</head>
<style>
    body{
        background: #80808045;
  }
  .modal-dialog.large {
    width: 80% !important;
    max-width: unset;
  }
  .modal-dialog.mid-large {
    width: 50% !important;
    max-width: unset;
  }
  #viewer_modal .btn-close {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999999;
    /*right: -4.5em;*/
    background: unset;
    color: white;
    border: unset;
    font-size: 27px;
    top: 0;
}
#viewer_modal .modal-dialog {
        width: 80%;
    max-width: unset;
    height: calc(90%);
    max-height: unset;
}
  #viewer_modal .modal-content {
       background: black;
    border: unset;
    height: calc(100%);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  #viewer_modal img,#viewer_modal video{
    max-height: calc(100%);
    max-width: calc(100%);
  }

</style>

<body>
    <?php include 'topbar.php' ?>
    <?php include 'navbar.php' ?>
  <div class="toast" id="alert_toast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
    <div class="toast-body text-white">
    </div>
  </div>
  <main id="view-panel" >
      <?php $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] :'home'; ?>
    <?php include $page.'.php' ?>
    

  </main>

  <div id="preloader"></div>
  <a href="#" class="back-to-top"><i class="icofont-simple-up"></i></a>

<div class="modal fade" id="confirm_modal" role='dialog'>
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="delete_content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id='confirm' onclick="">Continue</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="uni_modal" role='dialog'>
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title"></h5>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id='submit' onclick="$('#uni_modal form').submit()">Save</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="viewer_modal" role='dialog'>
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
              <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="fa fa-times"></span></button>
              <img src="" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script>
     window.start_load = function(){
    $('body').prepend('<di id="preloader2"></di>')
  }
  window.end_load = function(){
    $('#preloader2').fadeOut('fast', function() {
        $(this).remove();
      })
  }
 window.viewer_modal = function($src = ''){
    start_load()
    var t = $src.split('.')
    t = t[1]
    if(t =='mp4'){
      var view = $("<video src='"+$src+"' controls autoplay></video>")
    }else{
      var view = $("<img src='"+$src+"' />")
    }
    $('#viewer_modal .modal-content video,#viewer_modal .modal-content img').remove()
    $('#viewer_modal .modal-content').append(view)
    $('#viewer_modal').modal({
            show:true,
            backdrop:'static',
            keyboard:false,
            focus:true
          })
          end_load()  

}
  window.uni_modal = function($title = '' , $url='',$size=""){
    start_load()
    $.ajax({
        url:$url,
        error:err=>{
            console.log()
            alert("An error occured")
        },
        success:function(resp){
            if(resp){
                $('#uni_modal .modal-title').html($title)
                $('#uni_modal .modal-body').html(resp)
                if($size != ''){
                    $('#uni_modal .modal-dialog').addClass($size)
                }else{
                    $('#uni_modal .modal-dialog').removeAttr("class").addClass("modal-dialog modal-md")
                }
                $('#uni_modal').modal({
                  show:true,
                  backdrop:'static',
                  keyboard:false,
                  focus:true
                })
                end_load()
            }
        }
    })
}
window._conf = function($msg='',$func='',$params = []){
     $('#confirm_modal #confirm').attr('onclick',$func+"("+$params.join(',')+")")
     $('#confirm_modal .modal-body').html($msg)
     $('#confirm_modal').modal('show')
  }
   window.alert_toast= function($msg = 'TEST',$bg = 'success'){
      $('#alert_toast').removeClass('bg-success')
      $('#alert_toast').removeClass('bg-danger')
      $('#alert_toast').removeClass('bg-info')
      $('#alert_toast').removeClass('bg-warning')

    if($bg == 'success')
      $('#alert_toast').addClass('bg-success')
    if($bg == 'danger')
      $('#alert_toast').addClass('bg-danger')
    if($bg == 'info')
      $('#alert_toast').addClass('bg-info')
    if($bg == 'warning')
      $('#alert_toast').addClass('bg-warning')
    $('#alert_toast .toast-body').html($msg)
    $('#alert_toast').toast({delay:3000}).toast('show');
  }
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#preloader').fadeOut('fast', function() {
        $(this).remove();
      })
  })
  $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
      format:'Y/m/d H:i',
      startDate: '+3d'
  })
  $('.select2').select2({
    placeholder:"Please select here",
    width: "100%"
  })
</script>   
</html>
```

Update: I have tried putting the following code :

```
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
      if($_SESSION['username'] !== 'admin'){
        session_destroy();
        unset($_SESSION['username']);
        header("location: login.php");
      }};
```

but I can't seem to get it working. Can I know where to add this code to get it working ?

Comment: user role. then simply allow only person with that role to access that page, else run a redirect.

Comment: This should be handled in server side. Because you have to check user permissions on a requedt

Comment: The `session_start()` should be before any HTML content

Answer (score 1):

Easy use this -> [PHP Session](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) 
Before you load the page check the sessions and if the user does not have rights to access the page redirect to any other page.
Example:

```
if($_SESSION['user_type'] == 'admin'){
   go to admin page...
} else {
  go to hell...
  header('location: login');
}
```

I hope it was helpfull!

Comment: Note that you’ll also need to `exit` after that `header` if you’re going to continue processing after that.

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to do it.

By the look of it you're not using any Framework and so, you don't have a routing system neither middleware methods. In this case what is there to do would be to always check if the authenticated user is an administrator or posses adimitrator privileges.
That is exactly the thing Dorvalla wrote on the comment of your question. In a way or another your system must have a flag which tells if the user is or is not an admin.

1. So if your users don't have an attribute "isAdmin" (or anything else you prefer) in the object. Do it.
2. Now you just need to always check if authenticated user is an admin and if it is not, just block access or filter what he/she can do at the selected file or view.

Optionaly you could create your own middleware where all PHP classes your system posses passes through there and them, it's easier to filter. That is the idea of a middleware.

Hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I do have 'user type' : $type = array("","Admin","Staff","Alumnus/Alumna");  , . I tried doing unset session and redirect to login.php but I cant seem to get it working. I know i m making a stupid mistake. Can you please tell me where should I add this code : 
```
if (isset($_SESSION['type'])) {
      if($_SESSION['type'] !== 'Admin'){
        session_destroy();
        unset($_SESSION['type']);
        header("location: login.php");
      }};
```